# What event is fired when a feature is edited?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, features, fields-attributes

When the user draws a new feature (line, point, etc.) in ArcMap, there are null attributes.
If the user enters values in these null fields what is the event that is fired?

*I want to control the entered values.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event is [OnChangeFeature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OnChangeFeature_Event/0020000000p2000000/).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need ArcObjects to do this.  Simply [add a domain](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n0000000p000000) to the geodatabase and set it up with the attributes in question.

Comment: That depends on how much "control" is required. The [Validating features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000z3000000) topic has a good overview of different kinds/levels of validation.