# ArcObjects OnChangeFeature event not firing unless you move feature

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#

I am displaying points, lines and polygons on ArcMap as features with an addin. I want my end users to be able to change features (move geometries, add vertex, delete vertex etc) and get the updated feature's geometry.

For this purpose, I subscribe to `OnChangeFeauture` event with the following piece of code:

```
IEditEvents_Event editEvent = (IEditEvents_Event)ArcMap.Editor;
editEvent.OnChangeFeature += OnChangeFeature;
```

`OnChangeFeauture` event is fired only if a feature is moved. For points, this is fine, but for lines and polygon an edit doesn't necessarily mean the geometry needs to move (dragged somewhere else).

I subscribed to `OnVertexMoved` hoping to receive events if a vertex of line or polygon is moved.

```
((IEditEvents2_Event)Map.Editor).OnVertexMoved += OnVertexMoved;
```

**UPDATE**
`OnVertexMoved` event **DID** work. It has a reference to the vertex as an `IPoint` object, which is fine. But when I checked `ShapeCopy` property of the selected feature (when that event is fired), it was not updated at all. So when should I expect to get `ShapeCopy` updated in an edit session unless it is moved explicitly?

Otherwise, I had to ask users to drag geometry as a whole a little bit even if they move just a vertex (to get their updated geometry). That doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Are the edits being done with something like the parcel fabric editor extension? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83167/why-is-my-onchangefeature-event-not-firing-in-my-parcel-fabric-editor-extension

Comment: It might be a bug. I have looked through some old code that responds to edit events (changing attributes, to make sure they're conforming in shapefiles) and the OnChangeFeature works as it says on the box. Note that OnCreateFeature and OnDeleteFeature also need to be handled as they don't fire the OnChangeFeature event...  is the event fired when an attribute is changed? If you're looking for changed geometries and not attributes then perhaps the OnSketchFinished event might help.

Comment: @JayCummins yes.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I am not dealing with attribute update, so I tried OnSketchFinished, but it didn't fire at all. I updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: If it's in a parcel fabric as you say then this is a duplicate of the question @JayCummins indicated.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson No, there is no parcel related updates here. Bing Maps is loaded as a base layer and features are added on top. All I care is to get updated geometries of features whenever they are changed.

Comment: So they're just shapefiles or geodatabase feature classes (simple) and aren't in networks or topologies. Interesting.. it should work. You say that the event fires if you physically move the feature but not if you modify only one vertex - that is strange! Your wiring doesn't look like mine, but that mightn't mean anything, can you expand a bit on how you're wiring the event and the prototype (first line) of the event procedure please.

Comment: As others have said, it should just work as advertised. OnChangeFeature should fire even on an attribute change. The shape of the selected feature wont change until the sketch is committed but you can find out more information on whats changing in the event by casting the IObject to IRowChanges or IFeatureChanges. Parcel fabric layers wont fire the edit events for performance reasons but you can hook into the object class events for those.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast obj to IRowChanges and loop to find what changed.

```
IRowChanges prowchange = obj as IRowChanges; 
for (int i = 0; i < obj.Fields.FieldCount; i++) {
  if (prowchange.get_ValueChanged(i) == true) {
    //Custom code here, this is the row that changed
  }
}
```